# MediaFire Rest API session signature SHA1?

Tags: .net, api, rest, sha1, mediafire

I'm trying to connect to [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com) using their API.

According to the documen the [`get_session_token`](http://developers.mediafire.com/index.php/REST_API#get_session_token) request one of the required parameters is:

> **signature**: a SHA1-hashed string that contains the following 4 elements in this sequence: email + password + application_id + API Key. For example, email: testemail@domain.com, password: 111111, application_id: 9999, and API key: abcdefghijklmnopqrst, then signature should be calculated as follows: SHA1('testemail@domain.com1111119999abcdefghijklmnopqrst')

The problem I'm having is with the SHA1, I don't know how to hash the string to the desired SHA1.
I'm using .NET (and I tried several ways) but I even tried with python (`hashlib.sha1('token').hexdigest()`) and it didn't work (tried accessing via Internet browser).

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of pattern I follow when creating string representations of some hashed data:

```
string data = "testemail@domain.com1111119999abcdefghijklmnopqrst";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
byte[] hash;

using (SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);

//You would use hashString for the signature parameter.
string hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```